# Working code fails when run as backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I am developing a client app on my PC. I have several modules connected to my network. The modules are boards I have designed which act as servers. I want the client to do a scan of the network every 15 seconds to see if there have been any new servers added to the network and if so, log them into the MySQL database and to determine which of the servers already logged to the database as online. Ones in the database which are offline are shown on a treeview in red, online in green so if a board goes down, I can check if it has failed or the cable damaged or some other reason for being off.

OK, this is the sub that does the scan

```
Public Sub ScanModules()

    Dim Mdc As ADODB.Command
    Dim Sr As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim check As String
    Dim modsonline As Integer = 0
    Dim l, a, b As Integer
    Dim repdelay As Integer = 100
    Dim result As Integer = 0
    Dim myser As String
    Dim scantime As String = Date.Today.Date & " at " & TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss")
    Dim modtype As String
    Dim serno As String
    Dim ismod As Boolean
    If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
        ' get the ARP table and parse it to see all IP and MAC addresses currently registered
        Dim sCommand As String = "arp"
        Dim sArgs As String = "-a"
        Dim psi As System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(sCommand, sArgs)
        psi.UseShellExecute = False
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        psi.CreateNoWindow = True
        arptable = ""
        Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
        arptable = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd

        l = Len(arptable)
        a = 90
        b = 112

        Mdc = New ADODB.Command
        Mdc.let_ActiveConnection(DBCon)
        Mdc.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
        Mdc.CommandText = "SELECT * from machine"
        Sr = Mdc.Execute
        nummacs = Sr.RecordCount

        ' look for Baart modules in the ARP table - MAC will start ea and be all decimal numbers
        Do While b < l
            myip = RTrim(Mid(arptable, a, 15))
            mymac = Mid(arptable, b, 17)
            If VB.Left(mymac, 2) = "ea" Then
                ismod = True
                check = Mid(mymac, 4, 2) & Mid(mymac, 7, 2) & Mid(mymac, 10, 2) & Mid(mymac, 13, 2) & Mid(mymac, 16, 2)
                For z = 1 To 10
                    If Asc(Mid(check, z, 1)) > 57 Then ismod = False
                Next
                If ismod Then
                    Cmd = New ADODB.Command
                    Mdc.let_ActiveConnection(DBCon)
                    Mdc.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText
                    Mdc.CommandText = "SELECT * from modules WHERE macaddr = '" & mymac & "'"
                    Sr = Mdc.Execute
                    If Sr.RecordCount = 0 Then 'module is not in database, add it
                        EthMsg = ""
                        sendmsg("ENQ", myip)
                        If EthMsg = "ACK" Then ' if reply is not ACK then either not a Baart or not actually online
                            EthMsg = ""
                            modsonline = modsonline + 1
                            sendmsg("SER", myip)
                            serno = EthMsg
                            EthMsg = ""
                            sendmsg("TYP", myip)
                            modtype = EthMsg
                            EthMsg = ""
                            sendmsg("EOT", myip)
                            If EthMsg = "ACK" Then
                                Mdc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO modules (macaddr, serno, modtype, ipaddr, active, assigned) VALUES ('"
                                Mdc.CommandText = Mdc.CommandText & mymac & "','" & serno & "','" & modtype & "','" & myip & "', 1, 0 )"
                                Mdc.Execute()
                                Mdc.CommandText = "SELECT * from modules WHERE macaddr = '" & mymac & "'"
                                Sr = Mdc.Execute
                            End If
                        End If
                    Else
                        Mdc.CommandText = "UPDATE modules set ipaddr = '" & myip & "', active = '1' WHERE macaddr = '" & mymac & "'"
                        Sr = Mdc.Execute
                    End If

                End If
            End If
            a = a + 58
            b = b + 58
        Loop

        ' now update the module treeview showing which modules are online by pinging them
        Mdc.CommandText = "SELECT * from modules"
        Sr = Mdc.Execute

        If Sr.RecordCount > 0 Then
            Sr.MoveFirst()
            For a = 0 To Sr.RecordCount - 1
                myip = Trim(Sr.Fields.Item("ipaddr").Value)
                myser = Sr.Fields.Item("serno").Value
                If My.Computer.Network.Ping(myip, 100) Then
                    Mdc.CommandText = "UPDATE modules set active = '1', lastol = '" & scantime & "' WHERE ipaddr = '" & myip & "'"
                    Mdc.Execute()
                    For Each n As TreeNode In frmMain.ModView.Nodes(0).Nodes
                        If n.Text = myser Then
                            n.ImageIndex = 6
                            n.SelectedImageIndex = 6
                        End If
                    Next
                Else
                    Mdc.CommandText = "UPDATE modules set active = '0' WHERE ipaddr = '" & myip & "'"
                    Mdc.Execute()

                    For Each n As TreeNode In frmMain.ModView.Nodes(0).Nodes
                        If n.Text = myser Then
                            n.ImageIndex = 7
                            n.SelectedImageIndex = 7
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
                Sr.MoveNext()
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I also have these two subs in my code

```
Private Sub ScanTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ScanTimer.Tick
    'BgdScan.RunWorkerAsync()
    Call ScanModules()
    Application.DoEvents()
End Sub

Private Sub BgdScan_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BgdScan.DoWork
    Call ScanModules()
    Application.DoEvents()
End Sub
```

You will see in ScanTimer_Tick sub I have BgdScan.RunWorkerAsync() commented out so it does not run in the background and this works great. If I unplug a board, it turns red on the treeview within 15 seconds. If I plug it back in it turns green. But if I uncomment BgdScan.RunWorkerAsync() and comment out the next two lines, it should run in the background but it crashes out with an 'ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code' at the line For 'Each n As TreeNode In frmMain.ModView.Nodes(0).Nodes' 22 lines from the bottom of the ScanModules sub. The exception detail is;

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index"
  ParamName="index"
  Source="System.Windows.Forms"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at BaartOLM.General.ScanModules() in C:\BaartOLM.VBNET\General.vb:line 291
       at BaartOLM.frmMain.BgdScan_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in C:\BaartOLM.VBNET\main.vb:line 631
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
  InnerException:

I have never used backgroundworker before so this is new to me. Can anyone suggest why this code will run OK in the foreground but not in the background?

Thanks for your help, Steve.

Comment: Using `frmMain` does not do what you think it does, a universal vb.net bug.  When used in a worker thread, it creates a *new* instance of the frmMain class.  Which has a treeview, but unlikely to contain any data.  So the index you use is very unlikely to be correct.  Strictly separate the gathering of the data from the code that updates the UI.  Using frmMain in the RunWorkerCompleted event is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for that Hans. So if I build an index of which boards are on and which are off then update the treeview in the foreground from this index that should work? I need to be pinging them in the background because there could be more than a hundred boards connected and even with a timeout of only 100mS this sub could take some time to complete which would be annoying if you're trying to enter new data or analyse data.

Comment: You should replace `Date.Today.Date & " at " & TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss")` with something like `Date.Now.ToString("d/MM/yyyy a\t h:mm:ss")`.

Comment: *"a universal vb.net bug"*. Um, no.  Not a VB.NET bug.  Default instances are thread-specific because they are meant to be thread specific.  What's happening here is someone doing the wrong thing twice.  Firstly, doing anything related to the UI in the `DoWork` event handler is wrong.  Secondly, using a default instance on a secondary thread is wrong.  VB.NET works how it works.  If you use it wrong, that's not VB.NET's fault.

Comment: The whole point of a `BackgroundWorker` is to do background work. Anything related to the UI is the very opposite of background work. It is foreground work by definition.  If you use a `BackgroundWorker` then use it properly, i.e. do ONLY background work in the `DoWork` event handler.  If you need to get data from the UI to use during the work then pass it to `RunWorkerAsync` as an argument. If you need to interact with the UI while you're doing the work then call `ReportProgress` and handle `ProgressChanged`. If you need to update the UI when you're done, handle `RunWorkerCompleted`.

Comment: You might benefit from reading [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?471889).